# Primefaces: Bind component value from valueExpression string

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2

I read some articles here and they always say:

> Don't create components programatically, all you can do by code is possible in xhtml too

So I have an interesting question.

I have component Calendar:

```
<p:calendar>
    <f:attribute name="value" value="#{column.properties['from_value']}" />
</p:calendar>
```

Or you can simplify it:

```
<p:calendar value="#{column.properties['from_value']}" />
```

### Properties

- **column** is *var* of <p:columns> component
- It has variable *properties* which is **Map<String,String>**
- In *properties* I have key **from_value** and inside it I have String : "#{bean.object.dateFrom}"

My question is:
How can i convert this string to ValueExpression ?
Because when I run this code. Inside p:calendar is value "#{bean.object.dateFrom}" ... I need to set it as valueExpression and not String

What I get:

Calendar: <kbd>#{bean.object.dateFrom}</kbd>

What I want to achieve:

Calendar: <kbd>02.11.2017</kbd>

-

### Same code but Programmatically :

```
public ValueExpression createValueExpression(String valueExpression, Class<?> valueType) {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    return context.getApplication().getExpressionFactory().createValueExpression(context.getELContext(), valueExpression, valueType);
}

...

Calendar fromCalendar = new Calendar();
fromCalendar.setValueExpression("value", createValueExpression(properties.get("from_value"), Object.class));
```

Hope it's clear what I want to achieve.
Thank's for replies

Comment: does it work with a plain jsf `h:inputText`? Creating value expressions is in no way PrimeFaces related https://www.google.nl/search?q=create+value+expression+in+code+jsf+stackoverflow

Comment: @Kukeltje I have edited my question. I think you don't understand what my problem is. I'm sorry, I'm not native speaker